# Javascript Dynamic Anchor parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to dynamically write some anchor tags to a div so I can click on them to be removed from an array.  But I am having a hard time figuring out how to get the value of what Anchor was clicked from the update function into the remove function.  When I get that alert to popup, it comes back undefined.

**I have this all split into different functions because there are other filters that I will be filtering by.

So if I have a list of

```
(x) 2.0 Dolby
(x) 3.0 Dolby
(x) 5.1 Dolby
```

Clicking on the (x) of 2.0 Dolby would then popup the alert saying that 2.0 Dolby was clicked.  Any ideas?

HTML Code

```
<select id="audio" name="audio" onchange="addFilter('Audio',this.value)">
    <option value="null"></option>
        <?php
            foreach($audioArray as $data)
            {
                echo "<option value='$data'>$data</option>";
            }
        ?>
</select>
<div id="audioFilter"></div>
```

Javascript Code

```
function addFilter(type,str)
{
    var value=type+":"+str;
    if($.inArray(value,filters)==-1 && str!="null")
    {
        filters.push(value);
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
    if(type=="Audio" && $.inArray(str,audio)==-1 && str!="null")
    {
        audio.push(str);
        updatePage(type,audio);
    }
}
function updatePage(type,val)
{
    document.getElementById(type.toLowerCase()+"Filter").innerHTML = ""
    for(var i=0; i<audio.length;i++)
        document.getElementById(type.toLowerCase()+"Filter").innerHTML += "<a id='remove' onclick='removeFilter(this)'>"+audio[i]+"<a><br>";
}
function removeFilter(val)
{
    alert(val.innerhtml);               
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

val.**innerHTML** not val.innerhtml

Comment: Wow, cant believe I missed something that Trivial.  Looking past the small stuff for a larger error, that didnt exist.  Thank you :)